# Values of ".env" variables are not displayed with "react-native-config"

Tags: react-native, react-native-config

I have created a **.env** file and installed the *"react-native-config "* package, but the **variable values are not displayed** (on ios).

Could you help me with this?

Thanks

*terminal :*

```
 LOG  Running "myRecipes" with {"rootTag":51,"initialProps":{}}
 LOG  ALL RECIPES ===> []
 LOG  -------------> undefined
 LOG  Error in getAllRecipes:  [Error: Cannot load an empty url]
```

*.env*

```
ENV=dev
const URL_API=https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch
const API_KEY=2asjioezarnfzeopa
const MAX_PER_PAGE=30
```

*App.js*

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux"
import axios from "axios"
import Config from "react-native-config"
 
import { addRecipes } from "../../redux/actions"
 
export const useFetchRecipes = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch()
 
  const getAllRecipes = async () => {
    console.log('------------->',Config.API_KEY);
    ...
  }
 
  return {
    getAllRecipes
  }
}
```

Comment: Please translate your title to English, as this  is an English language site.

Answer (score 1):

```
The issue is in your .env file, remove the constant declaration as shown following:



    ENV=dev

    URL_API=https://api.spoonacular.com/recipes/complexSearch
    API_KEY=2asjioezarnfzeopa
    MAX_PER_PAGE=30
```